# Given an annulus with known dimensions how would I find the length of a line connecting the inner and outer edges at an arbitrary angle?

Tags: geometry

Given an annulus with origin `A` and radii `R1` & `R2`, a point on the inner radius `B`, and an angle `theta` to an unknown point on the outer radius `C` I need to find the length of line segment `BC`.

I'm working in OpenSCAD so I must solve this problem mathematically but I have diagrammed it in FreeCAD below.

[image]

- knowns: `A`, `B`, `R1`, `R2`, `theta`
- unknowns: `C`

Comment: in triangle $ABC$ we know side $AB$, side $AC$, and angle $ABC$. We want to find the third side $BC$

Comment: Lozenges... thank you. I made this way too hard in my head /facepalm

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles onto this page, here is the solution directly from my openscad file: `theta = 180 - vaneAngle; chordLength = innerRadius * cos(theta) + sqrt(pow(outerRadius, 2) - pow(innerRadius, 2) * pow(sin(theta), 2));` and yes it is for a centrifugal blower :)